# CSS Auto height problem form in banner | Wordpress

Tags: css

I am trying to fix a height problem, there is a form with several steps inside a banner.

It turns out that the form uses ajax and it is not necessary to reload the web, then when the user goes to the next step, the form in step 2 is more extensive than step 1, so the height of the banner exceeds everything, even the footer is passed.

This is the url to test https://whole-souled-lee.000webhostapp.com/anunciate-1/

And this is an image to see what happend [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5RHW.png).

Any help is welcome, thanks.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it, [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying adding this to your css file.

```
body.page-id-1001 div.banner {
 overflow:scroll;
}
```

Comment: How did you know that? awesome! thanks, Would there be a way to make the banner height dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

Viewing the html it seems that the div with the background does not contain the form div